# Monkey patching a core class with business logic with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

I have a monkeypatched of `ActiveRecord find` with some business logic, for example:

```
# lib/core_extensions/active_record/finder_methods/finder.rb
module ActiveRecord
  module FinderMethods
    def find(*args)
      return super if block_given?  

      #... business logic code =>  my_error_control = true

      raise "My Error" if my_error_control
      retorn = find_with_ids(*args)
    end
  end
end
retorn
```

I have not seen many examples like this, and this causes me a doubt:

Where should `finder.rb` be?

In this example, this file is in `lib/core_extensions/...` but if it contains **business logic**, I think `finder.rb` should lives in the folder `app/core_extensions/` **isn't it?**

---

Edited, after Sergio Answer

things like this, are a bad practice?

```
# lib/core_extensions/nil_class/image_attributes.rb
# suport for product images attributes
class NilClass
  def main_image(size,evita_video)
    "/images/paperclip_missing/original/missing.png"
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, it may be not the most helpful answer, but I'd suggest you should not mix business logic with `ActiveRecord` code, esp. in a monkey-patching way. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: Well, I have many of "monkeypatchings" with some logic, in this case with `find`, is to have a control for non authorized access: `find` receives a parameter that is de company that the object searched has to own  (   when user seeks a Family `Family.find(params[family_id],session[:company_id])` this `find` will compare the company of the family result `family.company` witht the parameter  )

Comment: RE edit: yes, most definitely a bad practice. I'd go with null objects (as @mrzasa suggests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where should finder.rb be?

Ultimately, it doesn't matter. It only matters that this code gets loaded. This mix of patching base libraries and adding business logic there looks like something that MUST be documented thoroughly (in the project's wiki or something like that). And if it is documented, then it doesn't matter. The code is where the documentation says it is.

That being out of the way, here's a design suggestion:

> when user seeks a Family `Family.find(params[family_id],session[:company_id])`, this find will compare the company of the family result family.company witht the parameter

Why not do something like this:

```
family = current_company.families.find(params[:family_id])
```

where current_company can be defined as `@current_company ||= Company.find(session[:company_id])`

Here, if this company doesn't have this family, you'll get an exception.

Same effect*, only without any patching. Much more futureproof. You can even add a couple of rubocop rules to ensure that you never write a naked `Family.find`.

---

<sub>* it's not like you add that patch and rest of your code magically acquires super-powers. No. You still have to change all the finders, to pass that company id.</sub>

Comment: I added this functionality to the finder because I realized that I had a lot of models that I could control by company, so knew that one solution was your one (as I can see now the best) and another solution I thought, was adding a parameter in the `find` that I wanted to control... It seemed easier to add a parameter than modify the object binded the `find`

Comment: so, the first question, where to put that, you have already answered, the question now if it is a bad practice, things like this (NillClass added to the question)

Comment: Thanks for your support

Comment: @AlbertCatalà: yeah, when you realize you have to patch NilClass, that is definitely a red flag :)

Answer (score 2):

It's the first time I see such case :). I'd put it in `app/core_extensions` and check if live reloading works correctly with it. If not, I'd move it to `lib/`. (It's  just a heuristic)

Edit:

Instead of extending `NilClass` I'd rather use regular NullObjects. It's really less surprising and easier to understand.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object

Comment: And, thinks like I've just added to the question (NillClass), are a bad practice? Thanks